# Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysql, chave-primária

Estou tentando fazer o update da tabela local com os dados da tabela cursoProunine com o seguinte comando :

insert into local  (idlocal, uf, cidade) SELECT idlocal, uf_busca, cidade_busca FROM cursosprounine;
, porém está dando o erro "Duplicate entry '2' for key PRIMARY, help-me please?

[image: Tabela Local]

[image: Tabela Curso Prouni]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu `SELECT idlocal, uf_busca, cidade_busca FROM cursosprounine;` está retornando o resultado como na segunda imagem que você postou, correto ?! Repare bem que existe mais de um registro com o `idlocal` com o valor 2.

E você começa o código com `insert into local (idlocal, uf, cidade)` ou seja: Você quer criar um novo registro para a tabela local com o resultado do seu SELECT.

Porém, para a coluna de chave primária idlocal da tabela local você está tentando inserir o valor '2', sendo que já existe um registro com esse id '2' em sua tabela local.

É exatamente o que o erro está te dizendo: "Valor de chave primária duplicada '2'".

Para você conseguir realizar o que deseja, deve retornar apenas um resultado do seu SELECT, experimente adicionar um GROUP BY idlocal, ficaria assim:

`INSERT INTO local(idlocal, uf, cidade) SELECT idlocal, uf_busca, cidade_busca FROM cursosprounine GROUP BY idlocal;`

Comment: Valeu Caio, deu certo, Obrigadoo!!!

Comment: Que bom que funcionou ! Disponha :)